# How to make this google script more efficient

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, processing-efficiency

I got this script to get into a folder and get the key for each file.

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Imported");
  var date;
  var size;

  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Data", "Size", "Id"]);


  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    date = file.getDateCreated()
    size = file.getSize()
    id = file.getId()

    data = [name, date, size, id]
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    //appendRow
  }
};
```

my problem is that taking too much time to finish going through the whole folder, it usually hits run-time limit before it finishes.

The folder contains 1000+ different files, we automatically upload files daily.

is there any way to make this script more efficient?

Comment: The script doesn't look inefficient. Perhaps you need to batch your work and or call your script more often than just once a day to keep up with the uploads.

Comment: Probably this is not exactly the solution you would expect to get. More like a way around. I'd consider to install Google Drive and synchronize all the files locally. This way you will able to handle them locally via system tools, Python scripts, node.js, etc.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list just under the specific folder using Google Apps Script.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your current script in your question.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- And, I thought that in your situation, when Drive API is used, the process cost might be able to be a bit reduced.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID. If you want to use "id" for this, you can use var folderId = id;
  
  // 1. Retrieve file list using Drive API.
  var ar = [["Name", "Data", "Size", "Id"]];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    const res = Drive.Files.list({corpora: "allDrives", includeTeamDriveItems: true, supportsAllDrives: true, maxResults: 1000, pageToken: pageToken, q: `'${folderId}' in parents`});
    ar = ar.concat(res.items.map(({title, createdDate, fileSize, id}) => [title, createdDate, fileSize || 0, id]));
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);

  // 2. Put the file list to Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Imported");
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

#### Note:

- From your question, I couldn't understand about the detail of your situation. So in this modified script, the folders in both your Google Drive and the shared Drive can be searched.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: it works perfectly! Thanks for taking your time to explain in detail the best solution.

Comment: @OPS Maheras Thank you for your response.