Google script or formula that based on the reference code in Google Sheets finds the corresponding file in Google Drive and hyperlinks to it
I have a Google Sheet array that lists details on every item for sale. In the first column is our standardized reference code (ABC#### e.g. "ABC0001", "ABC0002", etc) for each item. Seperately, I create an individual customised specification sheet (pdf) for each item and store it in Google Drive.
The filename for the individual specs is based on a standardised pattern (Year Model ReferenceCode "specs", e.g. "2014 Cherokee ABC0001 specs"). The folders are 3 levels deep and follow the below general format.
Top Level (Let's call it "Cars For Sale")
---> Cherokee
------> 2014 Cherokee ABC0001
---------> 2014 Cherokee ABC0001 Sales Package (allowed to be shared publicly)
------------> 2014 Cherokee ABC0001 specs file (this is what the Google Sheet needs to hyperlink)
------> 2011 Cherokee ABC0042
---------> 2011 Cherokee ABC0042 Sales Package (allowed to be shared publicly)
------------> 2011 Cherokee ABC0042 specs file (this is what the Google Sheet needs to hyperlink)
---> Mustang
------> 2001 Mustang ABC0027
---------> 2001 Mustang ABC0027 Sales Package (allowed to be shared publicly)
------------> 2001 Mustang ABC0027 specs file (this is what the Google Sheet needs to hyperlink)

I'm looking for a formula or script that using the Reference Code (e.g. ABC0001) in my Google Sheet, searches for the spec in my Google Drive and then creates a internal (non-shared) hyperlink to the file directly. That way once I create the spec, the Google Sheet will automically link to the spec so I can quickly reference it while on a sales call. I want to be able to click on the Reference Code say "ABC0001" in Column A and it opens in a new tab the pdf specification file.
If there is already a script that does this then please let me know.
I already have another column that uses the following formula to link to another Google Sheet with technical details on the item. Not sure if I can adapt this to do what I need or if there is a simpler way?
=ifna(HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/",indirect(CELL("address",INDEX('Filenames Script'!$B:$B,MATCH(concatenate("*",$A2,"*"),'Filenames Script'!$A:$A,0))))),IMPORTRANGE(indirect(CELL("address",INDEX('Filenames Script'!$B:$B,MATCH(concatenate("*",$A2,"*"),'Filenames Script'!$A:$A,0)))),"Output!$B$1")))
I have a script called "Filenames Script" that lists each file, but only in one specific directory level.
function listFilesInFolder(id) {
  var folderId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Please set the folder ID. If you want to use "id" for this, you can use var folderId = id;
  
  // 1. Retrieve file list using Drive API.
  var ar = [["Name", "ID", "Date", "Size"]];
  var pageToken = "";
  do {
    const res = Drive.Files.list({corpora: "allDrives", includeTeamDriveItems: true, supportsAllDrives: true, maxResults: 1000, pageToken: pageToken, q: `'${folderId}' in parents`});
    ar = ar.concat(res.items.map(({title, id, createdDate, fileSize}) => [title, id, createdDate, fileSize || 0]));
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while(pageToken);

  // 2. Put the file list to Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Filenames Script");
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}


Is your script from this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67654874 If my understanding is correct, first, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. By the way, in your situation, you want to retrieve all files under several folders including subfolders. Is my understanding correct? And, can I ask you about the details of the relationship between your question and your showing formula?

Yes, I used the script from that thread to link to other google sheets. However, in this case I want to hyperlink automatically to files in my Google Drive using the reference code. I guess showing the formula is confusing the matter as I want something slightly different.

Thank you for replying. About Yes, I used the script from that thread to link to other google sheets., I understood it. About I guess showing the formula is confusing the matter as I want something slightly different., I understood that your formula is not related to your question. About in this case I want to hyperlink automatically to files in my Google Drive using the reference code., I couldn't understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Well it is related to the question, but I'm looking to either adjust it to link to a google drive file automatically instead of a google sheet in one directory. Or if there is a cleaner solution using only a script without having to map out in a new tab my google drive files.

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

You want to hover over a code and open a specific PDF file.
There may be many ways of doing this. In this answer, a script (triggered by using a custom menu) converts the code from text to a hyperlink formula. If new codes are added to the list, just re-run the script (from the menu).
The script logic is:

loop though the data
use the "Code" and the "Name" to create the name of the relevant pdf file.
use getFilesByName to get the pdf file. This assumes that there is only one file of this name on the Drive.
use setFormula to create a HYPERLINK formula and replace the Code with the formula.

Hover over the Code to see a thumbnail of the PDF; click he thumbnail to open the PDF.

function onOpen(e) {
  // Add a custom menu to the spreadsheet.
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Update Code links', 'linkPDF')
      .addToUi();
}

function linkPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var salesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales")
  var range = salesSheet.getDataRange()
  var data = range.getValues()
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    var code = data[i][0]
    var name = data[i][1]
    
    // 2011 Cherokee ABC0042 specs
    var fileName = name+" "+code+" specs.pdf"
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i: "+i+", code: "+code+", name: "+name+", file name: "+fileName)
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName)
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: File name: "+file.getName()+", file url: "+file.getUrl())
      salesSheet.getRange(i+1,1).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + file.getUrl() + '", "' + code + '")')
    }
  } 
}


SAMPLE - Before

SAMPLE - After

